# Drupal 7 in paypal module add extra charges

Tags: php, paypal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have an eshop in drupal 7. I have also paypal payment method. 
I use the paypal  modulde "PayPal WPS" (version 7.x-1.0) 
and my drupal version is 7.22

When my customers choose and pay via paypal, paypal charge me some euros.

My question is how can I make to add in the final price paypal extra charges.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

http://thefeecalculator.com/

Amounts are based on $.30 transaction fee, and 2.9% of the transaction.

problem solved
=)

Comment: The problem isnt the maths!! but how can add the math type in payment module via CODE (php)

Comment: Nice calculator. Thanks

Comment: function memfees($amount)
{
    $amount += .30;
    return $amount / (1 - .029);
}. So open the payment module and edit the line that displays the total price by adding the calculation.

Comment: Do you know where exacly is the payment method module in drupal 7? The paypal payment method??

Comment: I would start by searching the module files for words that indicate total or checkout or something like that, you can of course make the search very fast using a code editor. Your OP question is very vague as you do not indicate the full name and version of any of the modules you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I have agree to your answer. Depending your country Paypal will charge to you. More information please find complete Paypal guideline regarding charges.>>https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/ua/acceptableuse-full